# Testing in Django with authentication

Tags: django, authentication, testing, swagger

I'm trying to test a couple of endpoints that require a user to be authorised in Django:

```
    def test_one(self) -> None:
        client = Client()
        user = client.post('/create', {
                            'username': 'bob.smith',
                            'email': 'bob@gmail.com',
                            'password': 'password',
        })
        token = client.post('/gettoken', { 
                            'identity': 'bob.smith', 
                            'password': 'password',
        })
        x = token.json()
        resp = client.get('/changepassword', headers={"Authorization": f"Bearer {x['access']}"})
        self.assertEqual(resp.status_code, 200)
```

However, it keeps returning a 403:

```
{"detail":"Authentication credentials were not provided."}
```

The content of x is:

```
{'refresh': 'eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzUxMiJ9.eyJ0b2tlbl90eXBlIjoicmVmcmVzaCIsImV4cCI6MTYzMTI0MTIwNSwianRpIjoiNDdjNzM5NThkNmYyNGJiMzkxMzRlM2Y2NThhZWI1MjEiLCJ1c2VyX2lkIjoxLCJuYW1lIjoiYm9iYnkuc21pdGgiLCJlbWFpbCI6ImJvYkBzZWNkaW0uY29tIiwiZ3VpZCI6NjA2NzU1ODI4NX0.lqdU5EfSA3DRbfxqum6XyvBc28t-vam8GVDq4W-NOsz7j9VTcg-i9AYQO0V-PLF7Lo89i6Pq50u0tZop7X5PMUryc3sCWPPnEsPyTm7Fi_cVV054E8chd-BP9fzykwW7ef7ufLTjzzPJfQdniq48jlRmce8Yjv_SspwoAhU2uYO54jtn2NNMRk80NckKyzxy9TwU9tItlPMCtoeK1SCucVsv-PfTJscxEXcaC347AZ0Dytqm2DVyDzQbt8RE9MKOXbHkhijeaftNBuiOMqJXE7NWQQ37iyF8bF2iPsc0M-T7ECFwsfFgPK_TD93ETCl9k_o6_6yxOHvx83dk6vGyzONJgl0MJ_W_y_B1UibQttBMoDfMwCxkM7akQ1OhL3ccb7GW-nGgqlOVREfxxW5xCN6h7O9cPMVk74jQ4xv2N6SlkEWIqb5UhQ4ZIJvFVrw-BOHLY_AqvnMadD9gYn7MaDPGXlpCX2EqOvOmKinASuSTJ94kXZ9pwMzuo_b-j5DnQWKgShZydpMZTt77TZ8_MZUtBBf7W-E_z71auQrgopgq82hHEpDfq3FoY4NXUq1IOEaJxJVpFcboXKep4WXQmRliRyqfIbwEAg7DOOiQ6cKrvbScPUKCpfYfzrt2f9fQbgtwwZYxHgW3-sLRP8r10UQzMaa8yR8ot-oQIq4xy5U', 'access': 'eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzUxMiJ9.eyJ0b2tlbl90eXBlIjoiYWNjZXNzIiwiZXhwIjoxNjMxMTU2NjA1LCJqdGkiOiJkZDliMWI3Yjc0N2E0YjcxYjJhZjg3ZGM0ZjUzODdmZiIsInVzZXJfaWQiOjEsIm5hbWUiOiJib2JieS5zbWl0aCIsImVtYWlsIjoiYm9iQHNlY2RpbS5jb20iLCJndWlkIjo2MDY3NTU4Mjg1fQ.dnlYgqfTvrQPBmAsZgJ5N39dtMANbBYE0kW3ZPCkAX8KWEsQrJwPQRbMYW_AetjowEkiSaWEQs8T4Hs553guW8lpdzg4_SiKjIXXodJJkfGNq9rDC9bpmLSJigVvpCM-AkgXsNUbZKrzP97fk5CZrVvyGszNlT1Oe66OSQrNQuaIqXSQ20XjuwzpSfEB3qJeC45LMgvHRBbEG0V2jOD5ReBxGJGoOPXVYS7vwfy7dLCq2iT-Kkpny4fALKjfM4bpux6UG5kJWrCLp2ybtCLTgJ9y4pvAhzEzmb1IeqtRV-gHQtaqTbMQl5cIhHdvmtMbBSQrzdG3yYqObKoyMW4oQLu8txKE4huptaInJcnXo4j2PFMPD-x3TtJOqOPYbfgb9Vu1-FCT0um5ZPnr9jv6j0ll92CuuHa7rBRatmzvLIJblpJ-ta6IkIZC6XkeEg3Sfg-dbnpSYaJ5fNxQm7r35oGj2j7r8fnvxlnYGPhmXJEdyas798Z001_TXrnHKsv2a1zNNJHQuK8sTmgAC4R1Fs0JQF4yBmIJ4TverKdiGOUHqYAYoEjNX69hdXeu_4AsAdUiRRzSYNbmuZFTEd-iREz0VgMs7QBIecVBzz33kFfgdYTy64qq9NDz3HIkzPbvw4xdGEFp8UTJlCfCFfdkzAT8pb_czC4xufdm9bSvK5E'}
```

Any ideas why it's saying that authentication details were not provided?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using django rest framework use `APIClient` rather than `Client`

```
client.credentials(HTTP_AUTHORIZATION='Bearer ' + x['access'])
```

[DRF Docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/testing/#credentialskwargs)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, although I'm getting the following error: "Client" has no attribute "credentials" [attr-defined]